# Why do I get the error: nameError: name tk is not defined, while I definded name tk?

Tags: python, tkinter, exec, nameerror

I am making a code editor. But when I type in my code editor the following code, it is getting a NameError.

```py
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="iets") # here, tk isn't recognized
        self.label.pack()
        
app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

All the code of the input tkinter text widget is executed by a exec statement. The whole NameError is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\mylanguage\execute.py", line 24, in do
> exec(self.input)
> File "< string>", line 9, in 
> File "< string>", line 6, in __ init__
> NameError: name 'tk' is not defined

Why do i get this error? in the code I typed in I do have `import tkinter as tk`!

The hierarchy of my project is the following:
I've 8 files: main.py, execute.py, output.py et cetera

- From main.py, the tkinter app is created.
- When i press button run, in execute.py the code is, as it says, executed.
- Then the output or error is being displayed in a toplevel window from the file output.py.

execute.py:

```py
...
    def do(self):
        sys.stdout.write = output
        try:
            set_last("")
            exec(self.input) #line 24
        except Exception:
            set_last("text.config(foreground='red')")
            error = traceback.format_exc()
            output(error)
...
```

when i add `print(repr(self.input))` on top of `do()` it outputs:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="iets")
        self.label.pack()
        
app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

See the whole project on github: https://github.com/keizertje/myl

thanks in advance!

Comment: The error message refers to line 24, which this code clearly does not have.  Show us your **real** code.

Comment: when i show you all my 8 files, my question becoms not really clear

Comment: look in my github repo, there you can see my whole prject

Comment: _when i show you all my 8 files, my question becoms not really clear_ Then make a **small** version of it, containing **only** the code that is critical to **this** error.

Comment: If I click on the link to your github repo I get a 404 error (is it a private repo by any chance?). Also, keep in mind that the idea of Stackoverflow is that the questions are self-contained and not dependent on external links that can change or disappear. Mostly so if someone finds the question in the future, they'll be able to grasp the whole problem (and hopefully, the solution)

Comment: Most people aren't willing to click on some external link and dig through a mountain of code to help you solve your problem.  It's your job to give us a **small** (but still **complete**) example.

Comment: @BorrajaX oh sorry i will set my repo to public

Comment: Any chance you have a file named `tkinter` or `tk` somewhere in your project that's causing a confilict?

Comment: i'm sure i don't have a file named tkinter

Comment: `exec` will run text as Python. Does that text (meaning: `self.input`) contain `tk` somewhere?

Comment: `self.input` is the text i typed in my code editor, see the top of my question

Comment: Show us the exact output of this code: `print(repr(self.input))` you can add this line at the top of `do()`

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean: self.input is the text in the initial snippet of code. Got it got it.

Comment: @JohnGordon it's exactly my code: 'import tkinter as tk\n\nclass App(tk.Tk):\n    def __init__(self):\n        super().__init__()\n        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="iets")\n        self.label.pack()\n        \napp = App()\napp.mainloop()' but then less readable

Comment: It seems like you're trying to do something like this `code = "import os;print(os.listdir('.'))";exec(code)` But this code does work, so your code must be different somehow.  We can't help unless you show us.

Comment: in my question I added a link to my github page. also i added the do method of execute.py. and the code i typed in my editor. wich code should i share?

Comment: The first reference to `tk` is the class definition `class App(tk.Tk):` on line 3, but the error is on line 6, so this is very strange.

Comment: I don't see how that can be the actual code string, because the indentation is not correct (although perhaps this is because it's hard to correctly format code in a comment, specifically for whitespace.)  Please edit the question and add the output of `print(repr(self.input))` there, where it can be correctly formatted.

Comment: Worked for me. No issue so far.

Comment: It may be because you used `from tkinter import *` in your main code and `exec()` by default executes code in current scope.  Try changing `exec(self.input)` to `exec(self.input, {})` so that the input code is executed in its own scope. I would suggest to use `subprocess.Popen()` to execute the input code in another process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry for the consternation, the reason of my problem was totally other than i expected! the problem was that when i put `self.input` in `exec()` the program starts with all global variables. how to fix? as acw1668 said: simply use `exec(self.input, {})` and it worked! this empty dict means that at the start of executing there are no global variables.

so `do()` becomes:

```py
    def do(self):
        sys.stdout.write = output
        try:
            set_last("")
            exec(self.input, {}) # here it's fixed!
        except Exception:
            set_last("text.config(foreground='red')")
            error = traceback.format_exc()
            output(error)
```

Comment: Glad to see you found a solution! That said, be *very* careful allowing for `exec` to run on user input. This whole idea makes me itchy, and should be avoided at all costs in any sort of "production" application.

Answer (score 1):

You file `execute.py` permits someone to `exec()` arbitrary code (here be dragons). In this case, the code includes an alias `tk` that is unknow in the context of `execute.py`.

Either `execute.py` needs to import and set this alias or the text file contents of `self.input` needs to do that.

For example:

```py
import statistics

text = """
print(statistics.mean([1,2]))
"""

exec(text)
```

or

```py
text = """
import statistics
print(statistics.mean([1,2]))
"""

exec(text)
```

If yourtext is your class, then this seems to work for me:

```py
text = """
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="iets")
        self.label.pack()
        
app = App()
app.mainloop()
"""

exec(text)
```

Comment: in the code i added at the top of my question is: `import tkinter as tk`. do you mean that?

Comment: execute.py does not have that import. I don't know what the contents of `self.input` are but whatever they are, they don't have that import either. So when you try to `exec(self.input)` there is nothing names `tk`.

Comment: self.input is the same as the text i typed in my editor and the code at the top of my question

Comment: so `import tkinter as tk` **is** in my code

Comment: are you certain?  It works for me if I do what my update does...

Comment: for me also, but when i use the rest of my files, it doesn't work

Comment: Did you upgraded pyCharm?